# Centos 7 How Grub2 Reinstall on Raid 0 Disks

Tags: raid, grub, centos-7

My dedicated server was not responding so I rebooted the server (CentOS 7). Now its showing there is "No bootable device found" . My system have 2 HDD's connected by hardware raid And 2 SSD's Connected by software Raid. I am thinking there is issue with grub 2 bootloader, I entered in Centos rescue mode, when I trying to reinstall grub2 by typing sbin/grub2-install /dev/sdc, getting error "Please specify --target or --directory"

lsblk showing below details system details
[Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdgwG.png)

Please help to install grub2. (also tell me how can I mount raid 0 disks in rescue mode, so I can take backup.)

I tried to install by typing sbin/grub2-install /dev/sda sbin/grub2-install /dev/sdc

but getting error of Please specify --target or --directory

Comment: Why do you think yo need to RE-install Grub? It never is uninstalled out of the blue... So, likely this is a X-Y problem. What yo probably need to check - and act accordingly - is hardware, namely the drives and/or UEFI/BIOS settings.